# gcc function call semantics for mismatch signature in caller/callee

Tags: c, gcc

I discovered something strange in gcc and hoping to get some input whether its a feature or quirk.
 Essentially I have a function defined in func.c as

```
void f(int a, int b, FILE* f)  
{  
   ...  
   ...  
}
```

There is no corresponding header file. But gcc doesn't give any warning when I call f(a,b) and gdb shows me that f is called with three parameters?
Why is this the case?. What is the semantics for filling up the third argument.

Comment: Just in case you're curious, the third argument is probably whatever value was left over on the stack from something else, and probably not meaningful (unless it happens to be 0 for `NULL`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `f()` doesn't have a declaration anywhere and is not defined in the current compilation unit, the compiler assumes that `f()` returns `int` and can take any number of arguments.

I know this is odd, but in the old days this was possibly a way to reduce the number of header files that have to be included, and hence faster compilation.

Comment: +1 this is a misfeature of C89 for backwards compatability that (I think) was removed from C99. If you crank up the warnings GCC will warn about this when it happens.

Comment: gcc 4.4 with -std=c99 warns about an implicit declaration by default (I did not provide any extra warning flags.)

Comment: I didn't expect it to have an interesting history behind it. Enjoyed it. Thanks for all the input. I have cranked up the warning all the way up.

Comment: This is slightly wrong. The compiler does not "assume `f` can take any number of arguments". That would be a variadic function, which **must** be prototyped with `...` in the argument list. Rather, the compiler assumes you know what you're doing and calling it with the exact number and type of arguments (after default promotions) that the function needs. If you break this contract, your program has undefined behavior.